# Fancy CSS shadow, possible?

Tags: css

I am currently coding a `PSD` file in `HTML/CSS`, and the designer used a somewhat fancy shadow. I can't figure a way to do it in CSS - is it possible? - If so, how?

Here's the shadow:

[image]

Comment: padding and multiple backgrounds with a gradient.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Next question.

Comment: I edited the question just for you, Matt!

Comment: I think this tutorial can be slightly modified to be what you're looking for: http://www.red-team-design.com/how-to-create-slick-effects-with-css3-box-shadow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on thgaskell's suggested link, you can use #box:before and #box:after to add 2 slightly smaller boxes with indices lower than 0 and add shadows to them. Use the shadow's color for the background color for these as well.

Here's a codepen that attempts to do this (you can tweak it to suit your purpose):
http://codepen.io/walmik/pen/fyidv

Here's another one tweaked more to the image you ve attached:
http://codepen.io/walmik/pen/eqpGk

**HTML:**

```
<div id='box'>Fancy Shadow</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Georgia. serif;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
}

#box:before, #box:after
{
  /*this is like appending a div element before the box:*/
  z-index: -1; 
  position: absolute; 
  content: "";
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 45%; 
  height: 60%;
  top: 15px;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #888; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px -15px 30px #888;   
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px -15px 30px #888;
  box-shadow: -2px -15px 30px #888;
}

#box:after
{ 
  /*this is like appending a div element after the box:*/
  right: 3px;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px -15px 30px #888;   
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px -15px 30px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px -15px 30px #888;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);    
  -moz-transform: rotate(1deg);   
  -o-transform: rotate(1deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(1deg);
  transform: rotate(1deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the CSS3 attribute box-shadow. The syntax goes something like this:

box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;

The drop shadow you're doing in the image above has a gradient, which is not possible with CSS currently, but a similar shadow would probably be something like this:

box-shadow: -10px -10px 20px #000;

You'll need to play with the numbers to get it to where you like it, but this should help you to start.

Comment: Actually, in the image posted, it looks like the desired shadow is darker towards the top than the bottom. A normal CSS `box-shadow` can't do that. Edit: Unless you angle it like walmik did below. I was thinking gradient, but angling it works, too.

Comment: Yep, thats why I said that gradients are not possible. But that angling idea is pretty good! I never thought about it. I'll have to try it out next time.

Comment: Ah. Yes. My reading comprehension seems to be a bit off today.